# Set pipe capacity in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

Is there a way to set the pipe capacity of pipes defined in a Bash (or other shell) script? Take e.g.

`cmd1 | cmd2`

In recent Linuxes the pipe capacity is set to 64KB by default. I know I can control the amount of data "buffered" between the two processes in two ways:

1. Using `buffer(1)`: e.g. `cmd1 | buffer | cmd2`
2. Using `fcntl(2)` with the `F_SETPIPE_SZ` flag from inside `cmd1` or `cmd2`

Each solution has downsides: `buffer` can only be used to increase the buffer; also writes over the default pipe capacity will still require waking up the downstream command. `fcntl`, as far as I know, can only be called from inside `cmd1` or `cmd2`.

My question is: is there a way, when the shell creates the pipe, to specify in the shell how much capacity the pipe should have?

Comment: Closely related: [Increase FIFO size limit](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/229529)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the pointer for now I ended up adapting your's and DepressedDaniel's approach. If nobody else comes along with a better answer I will just post my snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on DepressedDaniel and Stéphane Chazelas suggestions I settled on the closest thing to a oneliner I could find:

```
function hugepipe {
  perl -MFcntl -e 'fcntl(STDOUT, 1031, 1048576) or die $!; exec { $ARGV[0] } @ARGV or die $!' "$@"
}
```

This allows to do:

```
hugepipe <command> | <command>
```

and the pipe between the two commands is going to have the capacity specified via the `fcntl` in the perl script.

Answer (score 4):

> writes over the default pipe capacity will still require waking up the downstream command

If your goal is not to wake up the downstream command too often, did you try using the `-p` option to `buffer`? It should cause `buffer` to hold writes until the buffer is filled to certain percentage. You might need the `-s` option as well to write large chunks.

Update: D'oh, the pipes between the commands still limit things. Maybe try using the following adapter program:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  fcntl(atoi(argv[1]), F_SETPIPE_SZ, atoi(argv[2]));
  execvp(argv[3],argv+3);
  while (1);
}
```

as in:

```
adapter 1 (BIGSIZE) cmd1 | cmd2
```

or even:

```
adapter 1 (BIGSIZE) cmd1 | adapter 1 (BIGSIZE) buffer [args] | cmd2
```

if `cmd1` still makes small writes.

Comment: By downstream command I meant `buffer`. `cmd1` can't write more than 64KB (the pipe capacity) before `buffer` needs to wake up. And that obviously applies between `buffer` and `cmd2` as well, since the pipe capacity is always 64KB.

Comment: @CAFxX Oh I see your point now. Updating.